# How add PHP 5.4 syntax support to Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: php, syntax, aptana

When using the syntax features PHP 5.4 (eg `[]` instead of `array ()`) in the Aptana's code editor I get a syntax error. Is there a way to add support for PHP 5.4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not yet.

There is a ticket for that at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4447

cheers

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 syntax support is currently available in latest version of Aptana Studio 3.However 5.6 syntax support seems unavailable.I already posted a question about it.